# How can someone edit categories without editing an entry

Tags: categories, permissions

I have set up all of the proper permissions for our client to edit categories, and this is working.  But so far as I can tell, there is no way to give access to the Admin -> Channel Settings -> Categories section without giving them access to the Channel Settings, Channel Fields, etc.

What I am needing is for my client to be able to see, arrange, and edit categories without having to go to an entry and switch to the categories tab.  Add-ons welcome.

Comment: I'm adding a comment here, only because I want to know if there is an add-on someone suggests that makes this possible.  I've long been frustrated that the categories panel is not accessible directly unless you give the member group access to the rest of the items under channel settings that I'd prefer they not have access to.

Comment: Great question, by the way!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't give that modular of access for categories. I highly recommend using [Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin) add-on to modify the CP's main menu tabs to essentially hide the areas you don't want them to find.